# Problem with custom mapped keys

Tags: miktex, texmaker, keyboard

I don't know if this belongs here but I am thoroughly confused on what's wrong and would really appreciate some help.

I have a Razer huntsman mini, this is a 60% percent keyboard, so I have remapped 3 keys using Synapse (Razer program), one for >, < and backslash. So I don't have to press Shift + ... or Ctrl + ... When I press the remapped key in windows, chrome, or anything else I get the thing I had mapped it to, I get the >, < or backslash. However, in Texmaker these don't work and if I copy some text and then press one of the remapped keys it pastes the text. I also went into 'configure Texmaker', where you can make shortcuts for different commands, If I press one of the remapped keys inside the new shortcut environment it gives me ctrl + V.

I don't know if the issue is with Synapse or Texmaker, but if anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it. I have been using this keyboard and latex for around a year with no issues like this, I have tried reinstalling MikTex, Texmaker, and Synapse. I also tried reinstalling the drivers for my Keyboard, but nothing has worked.

Comment: I suspect you will need to contact the texmaker developers at https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/#contact

Comment: Do you know anything about response time?

Comment: no I know nothing at all I just googled for their support address